# The module is not compatible with your X-Cart version

Tags: x-cart

I am creating a module for x-cart. I am following this tutorial

http://kb.x-cart.com/display/XDD/Step+1+-+creating+simplest+module

The module is showing up in the modules list in admin panel but it says `The module is not compatible with your X-Cart version.`

My x-cart version is 5.2.4 . Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry this was a problem with the article. You need to define the getMajorVersion() method of your module as:

```
public static function getMajorVersion()
{
    return '5.2';
}
```

not as defined in the article:

```
public static function getMajorVersion()
{
    return '5.1';
}
```

I have corrected the doc and it should not be a problem for future references.

Thank you!

Tony